# Add css style elements only for specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to add CSS styling that works only when a specific URL is loaded. I have a URL that has ***/service/*** at the end. Only for this I want some  CSS styling to work on a specific Div (myDiv). Is there a way? I cannot add an ID to the body tag of that service page. The page is backoffice generated.

Comment: _The page is backoffice generated._ what does that means?

Comment: if(this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) == 'service') {//your css styling through js}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url.match("/service/$")` will match if the url endswith `/service/` because `$` means `endWith` in a `.match()`

**Update:** To get the url use: `window.location.href.match("/service/$")`

```js
var url = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/service/"
if (url.match("/service/$")) {
  $('#url').css("background-color", "yellow")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="url"> url </div>
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to do the same but leaving out the:  var url = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/service/" ? So I don't have to specify the full URL path.

Comment: Sorry Carsten, but where do I place:  window.location.href.match("/service/$")

Comment: any ways with css only?

Answer (score 1):

Try with CSS only

```css
[href$='home']{
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<a href="something/home">home</a>
<a href="something/home/somethingelse">home</a>
```

Comment: How does this add a css style to an element if the url of the current page ends with a specific string?

Comment: ok my bad i misunderstood the question. Question is for the url of the page.I thought for a anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/service/') !== -1) {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").className += ' specialclass';
}
```

Comment: You code checks if the `href` contains `/service/` and not if it endswith